# When listing features of something, do I need to use "it" before "has"?

Tags: grammaticality

For example:

The smartphone is blue, small, lightweight, (it) has three buttons, two cameras...

Is the "it" relevant? Can I omit it?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I would probably use two different sentences; one for the description of the phone itself and another for its features. "*The smartphone is blue, small, and lightweight. It has three buttons, two cameras...*"

Answer (score 1):

I would say that with the *it* (and probably even without it) it is a run-on sentence/comma-splice which should be avoided. A possible solution would be to use *with three buttons* instead, or use a semi-colon before *it*.

> *The smartphone is blue, small, and lightweight; it has three buttons, two cameras...*

Answer (score 1):

It isn't incorrect, just unnecessary. Consider this shorter example:

> The smartphone is blue, has three buttons, and is lightweight.

Compared to:

> The smartphone is blue, it has three buttons, and it is lightweight.

They're both acceptable, but whenever you can use fewer words to convey the same message, usually you should.

Comment: The crucial difference between the original sentence and your example is the conjunction _and_ which turns this into two main clauses separated by a conjunction. That is fine, as opposed to the (original) version without the _and_. Oh, and it should be 'fewer words' ;)

Comment: @OliverMason Thanks, I assumed the ellipsis was not a literal example, and the OP meant that the sentence actually continues. I'm sure that's the case and he's writing some copy (in which case, the *fewer* words the better). Does my edit make sense to you? I may be out of my element on this site, I don't really have the technical chops.

Comment: Yes, your examples are fine in that they show that the _it_ is optional. I agree with your comment on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you write a sentence that enumerates items on a list, the entries should appear as a parallel series of items, which you can think of as parallel limbs branching off the trunk of a tree. The question is, What is the trunk?

In your example, the first six words, "The smartphone is blue, small, lightweight," signals to readers that the trunk of the sentence is "The smartphone is": the next three words ("blue, small, lightweight") branch out from that trunk in parallel.

But the fourth entry in your list breaks the established parallelism by introducing another verb ("has"). Logically the trunk plus limb here reads "The smartphone is has three buttons," which doesn't work as normal English. Of course, readers can mentally correct the inconsistency for you, but they shouldn't have to.

You can deal with the problem in several ways. One approach is to change the trunk from "The smartphone is" to simply "The smartphone":

> The smartphone is blue, is small, is lightweight, has three buttons, has two cameras...

Another is to treat the list as a series of parallel saplings:

> The smartphone is blue; it is small; it is lightweight; it has three buttons; it has two cameras...

But both of those strategies produce rather awful-sounding results, at least in this instance. So your wisest course here is probably to follow Oliver Mason's suggestion and break the single, long, inconsistently parallel series of entries into two shorter, internally consistent series of parallels:

> The smartphone is blue, small, and lightweight; it has three buttons, two cameras...

Comment: This answer is both accurate and creative. Furthermore, various types of non-parallel construction are becoming FAR too common. ("We ate cake, candy, and played games." "He was tall, strong, and rode horses.") You see it all the time, and it drives me nuts!

Comment: Sven Yargs  By the way, the semicolon is a good suggestion, but "and" is usually and preferably not used after a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, John M. Landsberg. Since Oliver Mason didn't use "and" in his original example, I'll remove it from the example I attributed to him.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me if you do use this sort of ellipsis, the reader will naturally assume that the omitted word is a repeat of the main verb.  So ..*is small and [is] lightweight; has three buttons, [has] two cameras and [has] a flash.* Not elegant, but OK. Change the semicolon to a comma, though, and you have not only a comma splice as Oliver Mason says, but something that would expand to *is small and [is] lightweight, has three buttons, [is] two cameras, and a flash.* ???